# Configuration error exception: configuration system failed to initialize c#

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a C# console application, which was working fine on my development server, client UAT server and client Live server for the past 7 months.

Now I added a few conditions and tested it on my development machine, and it worked. Then I deployed the exe to the client's UAT server and it worked, too. But when I deployed the same copy to the client's live server, I am getting an error:

> Configuration error exception: configuration system failed to initialize

This is my CONFIG file for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="APPDB" connectionString="connectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="RUN_TES_ONLY_FOR_FIRST_PAGE" value="N" />
  </appSettings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          transferMode="Streamed">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
            maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
        contract="FileServer.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService"/>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Note: my application is working fine in development and UAT environments, but not on the live environment.

Edit 1: I am getting the error on this line of code:

```
return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["APPDB"].ConnectionString;
```